# Using \includegraphics within the caption of a figure

Tags: graphics, captions

Is it possible to use `\includegraphics` within the caption of a figure?  When I try, I get an error.  Here is a complete (sans graphics) minimal example that also demonstrates *why* I want to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Triangle}{\raisebox{-0.3em}{\includegraphics[height=1.25em]{triangle}}}

\begin{document}

% this use of \Triangle below works fine:
\Triangle

\begin{figure}[ht]
%  \includegraphics{...}
   \caption{example caption \Triangle . }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I do this because I need to include small symbols into the text, which I have as PDF graphics (it's not just a basic triangle---I know I could get that as a character).  If I remove the `\newcommand` part and just do a plain `\includegraphics`, I get the same error.

This is the error I get:

```
./Untitled.tex:12: Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12    \caption{example caption \Triangle . }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `\protect` (because `\Triangle` is fragile) or create a robust command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Triangle}{\raisebox{-0.3em}{\includegraphics[height=1.25em]{triangle}}}

\begin{document}

% this use of \Triangle below works fine:
\Triangle

\begin{figure}[ht]
%  \includegraphics{...}
   \caption{example caption \protect\Triangle .}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With a robust command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Triangle}{\raisebox{-0.3em}{\includegraphics[height=1.25em]{triangle}}}

\begin{document}

% this use of \Triangle below works fine:
\Triangle

\begin{figure}[ht]
%  \includegraphics{...}
   \caption{example caption \Triangle .}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```